# Maven producing EAR, how do I get WAR?

Tags: maven, build, ear

I'm fairly new to Java/build management and a part of my task is to build a project and run it. I was told to run WAR file under Tomcat. I using maven install command.
I build the app but all I can see is EAR file. I have no idea what is the next step.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pom.xml should have this `<packaging>war</packaging>` it would be `<packaging>ear</packaging>` now

Answer (score 0):

Probably the `pom.xml` file in your project has `packaging` defined as `ear`. Change that to `war`.